# ConcurrentLinkedQueue first strange CAS when first node offering?

Tags: java, cas

Debug the method “offer” in ConcurrentLinkedQueue make me confused.That is the point:

main method:

```
public class TestConcurrentLinkedQueue {
    public static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> concurrentLinkedQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        concurrentLinkedQueue.add("firstNode");
    }
}
```

key source code:

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
        checkNotNull(e);
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e);
        for (Node<E> t = tail, p = t;;) {
            Node<E> q = p.next;
            if (q == null) {
                // p is last node
                ***if (p.casNext(null, newNode))*** {
                    // Successful CAS is the linearization point
                    // for e to become an element of this queue,
                    // and for newNode to become "live".
                    if (p != t) {
                        // hop two nodes at a time
                        casTail(t, newNode);  // Failure is OK.
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                // Lost CAS race to another thread; re-read next
            }
            else if (p == q){
                // We have fallen off list.  If tail is unchanged, it
                // will also be off-list, in which case we need to
                // jump to head, from which all live nodes are always
                // reachable.  Else the new tail is a better bet.
                p = (t != (t = tail)) ? t : head;
            }
            else{
                // Check for tail updates after two hops.
                p = (p != t && t != (t = tail)) ? t : q;
            }
        }
    }
```

data stack before executing ***if (p.casNext(null, newNode))***:

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> this ={ConcurrentLinkedQueue@492} size = 0
head = {ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490,item = null,next = null} 
tail = {ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490,item = null,next = null}
newNode = {ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@493,item="firstNode",next = null} 
t = {ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490,item = null,next = null} 
p = {ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490,item = null,next = null}
q = null
```

data stack after executing ***if (p.casNext(null, newNode))***:

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> this ={ConcurrentLinkedQueue@492} size = 1
head = {ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@493,item ="firstNode",next = null} 
tail = {ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490,item = null,next=
ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490}  
newNode = {ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@493,item="firstNode",next = null} 
t = {ExtendConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490,item=null,next= ExtendConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490} 
p = {ExtendConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490,item = null,next = ExtendConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node@490}
q = null
```

Why the method ***(p.casNext(null, newNode))*** could make the head point to the new node and the other variable(tail,p,t) point to the self,but just execute the function to compare **P**’s **next** to be the new node.

Comment: Did you look at the code of casNext?

Comment: the casNext is a native method,So I don't dig it .For **p.casNext(null, newNode)** ,the main operation is to compare the field 'next' of node P. If the next is null,then set it to be the newNode.But the result is not as my thought.It appears that it do more